# I can't sort listview string in android

Tags: java, android, sorting, compare

I tried to learn from [Android: How to sort data for ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149994/android-how-to-sort-data-for-listview) But I can't sort `Flights` I sorting by select in spinner(position=1) I want to sort String in  `Flights`

```
        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        Spinner sort1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sort1);
        String[] sortName;
        sortName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sort_enroute);
        ArrayAdapter<String> ADT = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sortName);
        sort1.setAdapter(ADT);

        final ListView list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        int arrLength = dataF.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; i++)
       {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put("Flights", dataF[i]);
            map.put("Types", dataT[i]);
            ArrList.add(map);
        }

        ListAdapter adapters = new SimpleAdapter(Result.this, ArrList,
                R.layout.column_layout, new String[] { "Flights", "Types"},
                new int[] { R.id.flightnum, R.id.DES });
        list1.setAdapter(adapters);


        sort1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                if (arg2 == 1) {

                    Collections.sort(ArrList,
                            new Comparator<HashMap<String, String>>() {

                                @Override
                                public int compare(
                                        HashMap<String, String> arg0,
                                        HashMap<String, String> arg1) {

        return arg0.get("Flights").compareTo(arg1.get("Flights"));
                }

                });

                }
            }
```

Comment: Could you please format your code? hit control(or command)+shift+F in eclipse.

Comment: Try removing the final in your array list, declare as public and try again

Answer (score 0):

After you sort the list, you need to let the adapter know that the data has changed. Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) out. Call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`